# How to make SCHTASKS run command?

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I am new to SCHTASKS and cannot get it to run a simple command. What I tried is below. The file c:\downloads\temp_w.txt is not created. What is wrong?

```
c:\downloads>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.503]

c:\downloads>SCHTASKS /Create /SC MINUTE /MO 1 /TN mydir /TR "dir c:\windows > c:\downloads\temp_w.txt"
WARNING: The task name "mydir" already exists. Do you want to replace it (Y/N)? y
y
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "mydir" has successfully been created.

c:\downloads>schtasks /run /tn mydir
SUCCESS: Attempted to run the scheduled task "mydir".

c:\downloads>dir temp_w.txt
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is ECC7-1C96

 Directory of c:\downloads

File Not Found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DIR is an internal command (see: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html)

The following should work (untested):

```
c:\>SCHTASKS /Create /SC MINUTE /MO 1 /TN mydir /TR "cmd /c dir c:\windows > c:\downloads\temp_w.txt"
```